# Can someone please tell me why my css won't link with html? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I named my css file newstyle.css 
Any change that I make to the css style sheet in sublime text won't show up when I look at the webpage.
How can I make sure my link works?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Ana Yasmeen </title>

        <link href="css/newstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        </head>

        <body>
```

Comment: Post live link or demo where you are facing problem as structure seems good but might be folder/path issue.

Comment: You mean before you change the name, it worked?

Comment: Go to inspect element and see if there is any error in including the file.The syntax seems alright

Comment: Try putting the CSS within a style tag in the document. If it works, you know the link was broken.  If it doesn't, it might be your CSS.  Also consider using chrome web inspector or developer tools in any other browser to see if there is an error.

Comment: Sometimes `sublime` doesn't save it you hold `ctrl : s` or `Command S`, can you save from  `file->save as` and then replace

Answer (score 1):

Your tag looks good so check your link to your css file ie, yourlocalwebsite.com/css/newstyle.css should list your css styles, otherwise the link is wrong and you need to rewrite it to the correct path.

Comment: What difference it will make if i will use rel after or before??

Comment: You're right, it makes no difference, so it must be how you're linking to the css file. Do you have a url to show?

Comment: Well i did not ask the question but i asked the same question to op. but please don't hight light the lines like that as it will affect the future/new web  development user.

Comment: Leo, no damage was caused, mate. :)

Comment: Yup.. but think about new user who just started to learn..they might be think like changing the placement will make impect..hope you will get my point. :) and sorry if my words are rude :)

Comment: As you've said, it doesn't matter. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I dont quite understand how to see if my css file is relative to my html file?

Comment: Paste this to the end of the home page for the url where your code is, and your css file will show in the browser. For example mylocalwebsite.com/css/newstyle.css

Comment: I feel stupid for asking but what do you mean mylocalwebsite.com?

Comment: Are you working on your code on your own machine or somewhere else?

Comment: ok i saved my newstyle.css...in a folder on my desktop called CSS

Comment: Leo if you docked the question I've fixed it, please get the vote back to 0 if you don't mind (if it wasn't you don't worry about it).

Comment: This is so frustrating!!! I have been trying to figure this out for hours how come it won't link? Is there a way I should be saving my CSS file to make sure it's linked correctly? How do I know I have entered the right pathway?

Comment: and where's your index.html file?

Comment: on my desktop in a folder called myportfolio

Comment: if both your html and css files are in that same folder, you don't need css/newstyle.css just call newstyle.css.

Comment: Hey i did not voted you down..m not down voting any answer till its totally wrong.. so don't worry as its not done by me.

Comment: So this is my css so far i was just writing this so check out if my changes were showing up

Comment: body {
 font-family: georgia;
 color: red;
}

Comment: @Ana do one thing.. put your index.html and style.css in same folder and just change the url in href="style.css" nothing else..check its working or not.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Thank you @leo the lion so much!!!! It ended up working.  I have been trying to figure this out for hours!!!!

Comment: Then please  upvote and accept the answer of Nathaniel as he shows the spirit to help you .. :) upvoted +1 :)

Comment: Leo you are a star, thanks mate! :) Ana glad we could help you today.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry one more question how can I accept answers and up vote? Sorry I am very new to this site.

Comment: Hi Ana click the up arrow next to the answer you felt helped you best.

Comment: There is only an answer by you on my question.

Comment: Click on right under the answer and click on up triangle. Thanx nathaniel  :)